# How to replace strings within dictionary values without using eval?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, set

For example, I'd like to replace 'Replacement' with 'hello'

Input:

```
D = {
    'Name': "String Replacement",
    'DictionaryB': {
        'Dictionary': 'Replacement of the String'
    },
    'DictionaryC': {
        'AnotherDictionary': {
            'name': {
                'ReplacementString'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
{
    'DictionaryB': {
        'Dictionary': 'hello of the String'
    },
    'DictionaryC': {
        'AnotherDictionary': {
            'name': {
                'helloString'
            }
        }
    },
    'Name': 'String hello'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this recursively, like this

```
def rec_replacer(current_object):
    if isinstance(current_object, str):
        return current_object.replace("Replacement", "hello")
    elif isinstance(current_object, set):
        return {rec_replacer(item) for item in current_object}
    return {key: rec_replacer(current_object[key]) for key in current_object}

print(rec_replacer(D))
```

**Output**

```
{
    'DictionaryB': {
        'Dictionary': 'hello of the String'
    },
    'DictionaryC': {
        'AnotherDictionary': {
            'name': set(['helloString'])
        }
    },
    'Name': 'String hello'
}
```

Note: The result has `set(['helloString'])` because, `{'ReplacementString'}` is not a dictionary, but a `set` object.